# How to fix gap between floor and doorsill?

Tags: doors, trim, door-frame, gap, threshold

(Disclaimer: I'm a DIY noob, sorry if this is a dumb question).

I have a rather large gap (~0.5 inches) between the floor and my front door's sill. It's really cold and apart from being an eyesore, I can feel a draft of cold air coming in. The cold air draft is coming from the basement below. The door itself is relatively well sealed.

[image: gap1]
[image: gap2]

What would you recommend I do to fix it cheaply? Just a lot of wood filler/putty? Seems like it'll look terrible. Maybe I could replace the door threshold, but I haven't seen any that are wide enough--this is an exterior door and there's a storm door on the other side. Plus that seems a bit harder to do.

This is an old 100+ year house. I also have similar but smaller gaps between the floors and walls in other rooms. I think I'll add some quarter round molding on those, but that obviously won't work for this gap.

Comment: Black silicone caulk. Or a chunk of backer rod for a temporary fix.